# split equally imline - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I draw a line over an image and I wish to split/divide the line 5 times equally and get the 5 points coordinates, in the script I have the line coordinates but I have no clue how to continue. I will appreciate any help. Thanks

```
clc;
clear all;

figure, imshow('pout.tif');
h = imline;
lineEndPoints = wait(h);

x1 = round(lineEndPoints(1,1),2);
y1 = round(lineEndPoints(1,2),2);
x2 = round(lineEndPoints(2,1),2);
y2 = round(lineEndPoints(2,2),2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just dividing the line into 5 equal segments?

```
>> x = lineEndPoints(1:2,1)

x =

    32
   327

>> y = lineEndPoints(1:2,2)

y =

    48
   485


>> a = (0:5)/5

a =

         0    0.2000    0.4000    0.6000    0.8000    1.0000

>> x = x(1) + (x(2)-x(1))*a

x =

    32    91   150   209   268   327

>> y = y(1) + (y(2)-y(1))*a

y =

   48.0000  135.4000  222.8000  310.2000  397.6000  485.0000
```